# Simulating dataset for class

Tags: simulation, odds-ratio, teaching

Not sure whether what I’m after is possible, but thought I would ask. I am trying to create a database with a dichotomized dependent variables and a bunch of binary (1/0) independent variables. I'd like to pre-set some associations between the independent variables and the outcome. Doing so is relatively easy - I basically run a binomial function to predict the outcome, where the #number_of_test=1 and the probability of an event = expit(b0+b1*var1+b2*var2.....), where b0=frequency of the outcome, and b1,b2,....=my pre-defined odds ratio for each covariate.

What I realize however is that the prespecified ORs are never fully retrievable when I run a simple GLM model on the final simulated data. This makes sense, since the process of switching from a probability of having the outcome to a dichotomized 1/0 variable has some randomness to it. One can see this for example by running (in R): `Y <- rbinom(n=1000, size = 1, prob=0.6)` and then `mean(Y)` multiple times -  the results change across individual runs.

All of this means that for each database I would generate, the obtained ORs are close to the ones I a-priori defined, but not exact.

Does that mean that there is never really a way to retrieve a prespecified OR from a single simulated database? I completely understand that one way here would be simulate the data many times and run the GLM on each simulated database – on average the prespecified ORs should be obtained. But is there a way of ensuring one gets the correct/prespecified ORs with only one simulated database?

Comment: This is not entirely clear. Can you clarify, how do you want to use this simulated data in class? Does this help?  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simstudy/vignettes/simstudy.html

Comment: thanks, I just edited my question

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ markup for equations, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated?noredirect=1   (and maybe make a more specific and informative title)